# Is it possible to calculate the optical flow magnitude for rigid motion?

Tags: image-processing, optical-flow

For objects in 2D plane, it is pretty simple to calculate the displacement vectors using optical flow algorithms such as SLIC, LK, Färneback etc.

But how it is possible to know the magnitude of the flow of objects when the motion is orthogonal to the 2D plane i.e the object size increases ( coming towards you ) or the object size decreases ( going away from you ). ?